# How to add scrollbar to panel in java, without borderlayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jscrollbar

Here is my code:

```
//this is a JPanel, the gray panel behind the A4 paper
public Panel(int w, int h) {  //w=624, h=600
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    ownlayout();
    setLocation(0, 0);
    setSize(w,h);
    setBackground(Color.gray);

    JScrollBar vbar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
    vbar.setLocation(w-30,0);
    Tab tab = new Tab(w-30,842);
    //Tab is a JPanel too, this is the A4 paper
    add(tab);
    add(vbar);
}
private void ownlayout() {
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    /*layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, w, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, h, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );*/
}
```

You can see, the Tab panel's height is bigger than gray Panel's height.
So I want, to get a scrollbar in the right side of the gray Panel, which can scroll the tab panel (which is on the gray Panel) up and down. But it only shows the tab panel, and there is no scrollbar!
I can do this, if I set the layout border, and not the ownlayout(), but I want a free design, not borderlayout.
Please help me with some example!

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the Swing tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on using layout managers and in particualar on "How to Use Scroll Panes" that should help.

Comment: Also, it's generally not a good idea to mix AWT (`Panel`) and Swing (`JScrollBar`) components this way.

Comment: than what should I add to panel, if not JScrollBar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JScrollPane thePane = new JScrollPane(yourBigComponent);
container.add(thePane);
```

Comment: the container is the place holder for your big component with the scroll pane